# How to use Mullvad browser in selenium on linux

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am struggling to use mullvad browser in selenium on Linux, If someone can provide some reference code then it would be great.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
service = Service(executable_path="mullvad-browser/Browser/mullvadbrowser")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

Upon using the above code, the mullvad browser pops up but the code is stuck forever on initializing the webdriver.